# Xamarin Forms, using an Interface class in all Android, IOS and UWP projects

Tags: xamarin.forms, using

I have an Interface class in the Xamarin forms root in Services folder.

```
namespace FirstPrismApp.Services
{
    public interface ITextToSpeech
    {
        void Speak(string text);
    }
}
```

I can't using the Interface class in the other included project like Android, IOS and UWP.

[image]

Comment: I've got this sometimes, have you already cleaned and rebuild? Did you add the Services project as a reference to to your Android, IOS, UWP project?

Comment: @Johannes Yes! Cleaning the project and restarting Visual Studio. Cleaning just not works!

Comment: Try this: remove your shared project reference from References folder  in Android project and add it again.